# Onomatopoeia for disgust

Tags: slang, interjections, onomatopoeia, exclamations

Are there any English onomatopoeias for disgust / loathe? What exclamations are commonly used to express repulsion?

Something that could be used like:

> (___) dog shit. I loathe it! *(some sound here)*

… to increase the expressiveness of the sentence?

Comment: Is _ugh_ onomatopoeic? NOAD defines it as "used to express disgust" with the example: _Ugh! What's this disgusting object?_

Comment: Grungy, slimy.  Also, "I loathe them.  Yecch!" or "I loathe them.  P.U.!"

Comment: @Tonepoet The accepted answer includes a number of onomatopoeias, including *yuck*, which is probably imitative of the sound one makes when vomiting, and *blech*, which is the sound one makes when trying to get something bad-tasting out of one's mouth.

Comment: @Tonepoet 'yuck' is onomatopoeic. totally appropriate as an answer

Comment: @Mari-Lou sure.

Comment: @Mitch good man :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The conventional exclamation for disgust is *[yuck](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/yuck)* (alternatively, *yech*); the Macmillan entry says it is

> used for saying that you think someone or something is dirty, ugly, or unpleasant
>
> > Oh, yuck! It’s slimy!

The earliest OED entry is from 1966, noting an earlier verb sense of *yuck* meaning to vomit, but it may have existed earlier in dialectic English.

Chris Sunami's suggestion of *[ew](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ew)* is also a good one.

Somewhat milder is *ick*, a reaction to something *[icky](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/icky)*. Somewhat stronger is *[blecch](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/blech)* (*blech*, *bleech*, etc.), which has not made it into any of the major dictionaries, but is easily found online, and even featured in the title of [an episode](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/New_Kids_on_the_Blecch) of *The Simpsons.* Stronger still is *[bleah](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bleah)*, also imitative of retching or gagging, though OLD labels this as *North American*.

Other onomatopoeia for vomit or vomiting, like *[barf](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/barf)* or *[yack](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/yack)* or *[hork](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/hork)* may be suitable, but the degree to which these terms is understood will vary greatly by region and generation, and some slang like *woof* or *hurl* may thus be ambiguous.

A broader term for something generally unpleasant is *[ugh](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ugh)*, as noted elsewhere, but this is more a term for dislike or disappointment.

Comment: "Eurgh!" is a more obviously disgust alternative to "Ugh".

Comment: @Muzer How's that more obvious?

Comment: @mbomb007 I meant that, compared to "ugh" which as noted is rather ambiguous, "eurgh" is much more associated with disgust.

Comment: I've never even heard "eurgh" before

Comment: +1, especially for *blech* (which is apparently in the M-W unabridged). I think this answer could be made even more explicitly in-line with the OP's request for "onomotopoeias" with an etymological note that *yuck* is probably imitative (of vomiting or, with a different meaning, of laughter). Your link is suggestive of this (there's a box with other "written representations of sounds: achoo, ahem, atishoo" linked), and [etymonline has a more direct statement](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yuck). (It's also the OED's best guess, but I can't link to that subscription service.)

Comment: You might want to consider reopening the question, because it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

The sound is "*ew*" --your face naturally contorts into an expression of disgust when you say it.  Or alternately, it's the sound you naturally make when your face is in an expression of disgust (contrast with "ooh").

> **ew**: (with as many extra ‘e’s and/or ‘w’s as needed for emphasis)
>   Expression of disgust or nausea.
>   Ew! There’s a fly in my soup.
>   Eww! This peanut butter tastes disgusting!
>   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ew

See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMBXhDcogcI

Answer (score 6):

I find "[gag](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gag)" to be both descriptive and onomatopoeic. (Merriam-Webster's intransitive sense, though their definition is actually poor, as a true gag is a neurological reflex.)

My teenager is also fond of using a sound like "bleah" (imitating a vomiting noise) to express disgust in an onomatopoeic fashion as in [Oxford Living Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bleah).

Comment: I think [*blech*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blech) is similar.

Answer (score 5):

I would imitate throwing up a little bit in my mouth!

> (…) dog shit. I loathe them! *[Bleurgh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bleurgh)*

The example given is:

> Used to express disgust.
> ‘bleurgh—just opened the fridge and it smells of gone-off chicken’
> ‘I can handle gore and everything but show me warts? Bleurgh!’

Its origin matches my assumptions:

> #### Origin
>
> 1960s: probably imitative of the sound of gagging or retching.

Comment: I replaced *them* with *it*  in the question.

Comment: *it* agrees with "dog shit" that's my thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

I think "retch" is a great example.

It's origins are ancient and it's not clear how the Old-English or Proto-German words sounded, but it's original meaning was "to clear the throat, to cough up phlegm" and even today's word evokes the sound of vomiting, not very different.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=retch

Comment: Can you support your suggestion with a definition and a link to the source? We prefer answers with supportive information and definition.